# SAPUI5: How to call a function from another function in the same controller

Tags: sapui5

I can't call a function from another function of the same controller.
What I have in my controller:

```
checkData: function(){
    if(//check the data here before submitting it to the server){
        //display error message if the data is not ok
    }
    else{
        //call the function that submits data - submitData
    }
},

submitData: function(){
    //make ajax call here
}
```

How do I call submitData function from within `else` block of checkData function?

### EDIT:

Here is the complete code of 2 above mentioned functions:
[Link to JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jigurahuliha/1/edit?js)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to use the "this" notation. Like this:

```
checkData: function(){
    if(//check the data here before submitting it to the server){
        //display error message if the data is not ok
    }
    else{
        //call the function that submits data - submitData
        this.submitData();
    }
},

submitData: function(){
    //make ajax call here
}
```

If the checkData function is **called inside an event function** then "this" represents the component that triggered the event and not the controller.
In this case, you could call the submitData function by using this syntax:

```
var oController = sap.ui.getCore().byId("your-view-name").getController();
oController.submitData();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried this before posting this question. I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Does it mean I have a problem in `submitData` function syntax?

Comment: Can you add the complete controller code for review?

Comment: Everything seems ok. I see you have are writing to the console on the begining of the submitData method. When you execute your code are you able to see the message "entered submitData()"? Also, from where are you calling the checkData method? Are you able to use developer tools to debug step-by-step your execution? Let me know.

Comment: No, I don't see "entered submitData()", I get error on `this.submitData();`. The checkData method is called from this controller's view by `press: oController.checkData` property of the button.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to access this from an event assuming it will return In reality, inside the context of an event handling function this is the component that caused the event. One option to solve this is use the sap.ui.getCore().byId("your-controller-name").submitData().

Comment: Sorry, this is the correct syntaxe: sap.ui.getCore().byId("your-view-name").getController().submitData().

Comment: Now I see  "entered submitData()" console message, thanks! In common, do I have to use this long syntax even if I call a function that is next after the "caller" function?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't fully understand your question. Nevertheless you only need to use this syntax if you are on an implementation of a event function or inside a function that is called by the event function. On such functions the "this" represents the component that triggered the event and not the controller. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: My view id is "application-APPNAME-display-component---detail", is there any way to get this view id by createId() ? Because this unique id seems not consistence in flp app and single web app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529014/how-to-get-the-reference-id-of-an-element-in-another-view-ui5/45008071#45008071 Seems no element way.

Comment: And how can i find the view name? is this somehting like "application-myappname-display-component---object"??