# How to get the reference id of an element in another view - UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

How can I get the reference id of an element in another view? Like for example I have the following file structure (mvc)

```
-view
|-- View1.view.xml
|-- View2.view.xml
-controller
|-- View1.controller.js
|-- View2.controller.js
```

Assuming that during runtime of `View2.controller.js`, how can I get a certain element in `View1.view.xml`?

Comment: Questions with "Assuming" in them are ofthen not good and tend to get dwonvoted. Provide us real examples, where the problem exists, and not assumed thought experiments. As you are new, have a look at the [tour]

Comment: You might want to have a look at model binding and (global) events. They could be an alternative to accessing the Controls of another view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *relative* navigation. Do not use *absolute* Navigation, since that will not work anymore if you change like from local html to a FioriLaunchpad.

Commands you might want to look at:

**Controller**

- [getOwnerComponent()](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.html#getOwnerComponent)
- [byID](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.html#byId)

**Managed Object**

- [getAggregation()](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#getAggregation)

Now you can navigate to the OwnerComponent, and there will be saved your target View, either as variable or as aggregation of your Element.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the ID of the element in View1.view.xml is "idOfElement". you can access the reference of that element in another view(View2.controller.js) of the same application using the statement:

```
                         var elementID = sap.ui.getCore().byId("idOfElement");
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, I am trying to get an element which id is `idAppControl` in App.view.xml, and I want to access it in Master.controller.js

Here is my solution:

```
var ownerId = this.getView()._sOwnerId,
rootId = this.getOwnerComponent().getManifestEntry("sap.ui5").rootView.id,
id = "idAppControl",
realId = ownerId + "---" + rootId + "--idAppControl",   
element = sap.ui.getCore().byId(realId);
```

`sOwnerId` is a private property, I failed to find a better way to get it.

My `manifest.json`:

```
"sap.ui5": {
    "rootView": {
        "viewName": "xxx.view.App",
        "type": "XML",
        "id": "app" // what I get in rootId
    },
}
```